# How do I make a Mario game on Netlogo?

Tags: netlogo

I'm trying to make a Super Mario Bros game on Netlogo. Any suggestions on how to go about that? Specifically, I need help trying to get Mario to jump and move at the same time.

To move left and right, I currently have the background scrolling left or right by asking the patches to copy the color of patches before/after them. Also, ticks are on.

Comment: There is not nearly enough information here to allow us to answer. Is your problem that you don't know how to code Mario moving (look up `move`) or that you don't know how to communicate to tell NetLogo when to make Mario jump? What is difficult about moving and jumping at the same time? What code do you already have?

Comment: You may be trying to learn too much all at once by writing a big program all at once. Write a really small program; get it working; attempt to make a very small improvement to it, and get that working; and so on. If at any point you get stuck, come here, show your code, and ask a specific question about it. Never stray more than a short distance from working code.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow Kasey! Please be nice to Kasey, as this is Kasey's 1st Question. It's always a good idea to post a working & re-creatable example of the code, which you're stuck with... plus enough details, so that we can clearly understand the issue. That let's us see what you've attempted to do, so we can try to help you to figure it out what to do next. If you get stuck making your side-scroller game, try following these guidelines when you ask your next Q & maybe you'll see some cool upvotes. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're trying to learn how to create a side-scrolling game.

I'd recommend going over [GameAcademy.com](https://www.gameacademy.com) & look up what Trés Smith is doing with teaching people how to create side-scrolling games. One example of a side-scroller is [Nintendo](https://www.nintendo.com)'s [Super Mario Bros.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super_Mario_Bros.) game.

Trés also runs [BuildBox.com](https://www.buildbox.com), which is an IDE for developing 2D games. I've seen some pretty cool videos on his site, for how to get started making video games.

I've also heard of these 2 sites, as being possibly good ones for learning new concepts through video presentations. I don't know if they contain video game specific material, but you may want to peruse them as well:

1. https://www.khanacademy.org
2. https://www.lynda.com

You might also check [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com) for how-to-videos on making side-scrolling video games.

Good luck!